# Crypto: Valid key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

Consider this scenario:

- Alice sends a signed message with her key to BOB.
- Bob never traded a key with Alice.
- Alice's key is signed by a certain X.
- X's key is signed by Y, an entity that BOB trusts.

Is Alice's key valid or not for Bob?

Comment: Please add some context on this question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **cryptography** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This is about PKI-X, but before answering yes/no you may want to consider that trust is not a black and white thing.

Comment: Trick question.  The validity of Alice's key does not depend on Bob's decision to trust it or not.

Comment: As noted, this belongs on either crypto.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com, but before you ask it there, you will need to make it more precise. Make sure you have a very specific meaning for "trust" (trust that the key is theirs? trust that they are a valid introducer? trust that anyone they trust is also trustworthy? Trust as Maarten notes, trust is not a binary thing.) You must also make sure you have a precise meaning for "valid" (as Thomas notes). The short answer is "probably no in most cases, for most common systems," but it highly depends on the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we trust Y so the X's key  is good! But we can not deduce a trust in X. The latter can sign anything and claim that it is the Alice's key.